# To what extent may someone use the content of a published paper in an expository piece on that paper?

Tags: publications

If someone *s* has a paper *p* published, and if *s* wants to write up a piece explaining the contents of *p*, then to what extent can *s* use the contents of *p*? Or, the person *s* has no right to mention the contents of *p*?

That is, if someone writes an article explaining the ideas in one of his published paper by rephrasing the published paper, then to what extent is such rephrasing legitimate?

Comment: By "legitimate," do you mean "what is acceptable from an ethical point of view"? "what is typically done in this scenario"? something else?

Comment: @ff524 Thank you :) Right, from ethical point of view. I am sorry to confuse you. I am not a native speaker in English, thus I may not express entirely clearly what I want to express. I appreciate your making sure with me. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From an ethical point of view, you must cite your original source appropriately. Clearly indicate

- when you are using ideas, words, or figures from another work by citing the source
- when you use something verbatim (typically by putting it in quotation marks or blockquotes)

As long as you attribute your sources properly, there isn't really an ethical problem with excessive use of a source.

From a legal perspective, it can be trickier. In summary,

- Copying large amounts of text verbatim: may violate copyright
- Copying small amounts of text verbatim, for academic purposes: typically allowed under [fair use](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fair_use), though like everything legal, this varies by jurisdiction
- Paraphrasing text: does not violate copyright. The intellectual content of a paper is not subject to copyright (as opposed to the words used to present it, which are).
- Reusing figures: may violate copyright. Check the policy of the source's publisher.

From a "best practices" standpoint, work that involves an *excessive* amount of paraphrasing is often lacking original intellectual content. Even if your work is expository, you're supposed to be adding some value for the reader, not just stating the content of the original source in other words. So be careful of this, too :)

Answer (score 1):

It would be better to avoid the abbreviations 's' and 'p', which is probably why @ff524 was confused.

Regarding the question I think it will depend on what you want to do with the material and the copyright conditions of the paper. Sometimes the copyright belongs to the publishers and each journal has specific guidelines for reproducing some content (even some allow to download figures in powerpoint format to be used for presentations under some conditions). Other times (e.g. open access journals), the copyright belongs to the authors. Either way, if in doubt the best would be to get in contact with the appropriate person.

Personally, for journal club and similar activities, I use the material without asking. In conferences, when I want to highlight someone's else research, I may include a figure of their paper. In that case I always add the appropriate reference to the paper.

Comment: Hi thanks for your sharing. Indeed, *s* and *p* are not abbreviations; they are symbolic pronouns. Mathematical language makes things concise by speaking in this style :) I feel that ff524 is confused not by language.

Comment: "Mathematical language makes things concise by speaking in this style :)" [Citation Needed]